# How to get the path of an embebbed resource?

Tags: c#, file, resources

I included an embebbed resource in my C# project; I know its name and how to refer to it, so I was wondering if there is any way to get its absolute path...is there?

Comment: Get to its absolute path from what information? What sort of "absolute path" are you really thinking of? It would help if you could give a concrete example.

Comment: I'd like to include an INI file to my project and then read it...

Comment: If it's an *embedded* resource though, it's in the assembly. At that point what do you mean by "its absolute path"? It's not a file you can just refer to.

Comment: What if I add a file in my project without embedding it? Is there any way to get its absolute path?

Comment: I think you're missing the point: you don't need the file path to refer an embedded resource. You did say that you know how to refer it...

Comment: I have an embebbed ini file in my project, and I'd like to perform on it the GetPrivateProfileString function, but I need the file's path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said, an embedded resource is embedded within the compiled assembly and does not exist on the file system; if you're looking to have the file on the file system you should change the build action to 'None' and the Copy to Output Directory to one of the copy values.

If however you do mean to embed the resource then it can be accessed by using the GetManifestResourceStream method of the Assembly class as follows:

```
GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("someresourcestringhere")
```

(The above code assumes you are accessing the resource from a class within the same assembly).

The embedded resource normally follows the following format and this is the string you would pass in to the GetManifestResourceStream method:

default project namespace.folder name (if any).file name

Any spaces in folder names are replaced with an underscore, any spaces in file names are preserved.

Personally I have found the easiest way to get this string is to use a decompiler tool (such as Telerik's Just Decompile) to have a look inside the assembly and get the full resource name for the file you're looking for.

Comment: I know this is a fairly old answer, but the one bit of information I wanted seems to be lost in a typo! You've said "any spaces are replaced with **spaces**". What are they really replaced with?

Answer (score 5):

Embedded resource is exactly that: embedded. It means, that it's included in the assembly and does not exist as a physical file after compilation (if that's what you're looking for).

Comment: VERY helpful! Thank you. Can you suggest an alternative for a .xml file I am trying to use reflection to locate? Thanks!

Comment: Embedded resources are simple to use without the need for reflection. If you want your data to be embedded (i.e. not configurable after build), use them. Otherwise, you may want to use ``Content`` build action to have the file in place after build - in that case use the good old I/O API to access it.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```